# Bean in jar inside EAR/lib folder possible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, ear

I have an EAR with the following structure:

```
myapp.ear
...META-INF
......application.xml
...lib
......common.jar
......specialBeanlib.jar
...myejb.jar
...mywar1.war
...mywar2.war
```

As you can see common.jar and specialBeanlib.jar are in the EAR lib folder.

myejb.jar contains the service classes. 
mywar1.war contains the user-gui. 
mywar2.war contains the admin-gui.

The ejb and the war modules are build from separate maven projects and are referenced in the application.xml file. The file specialBeanlib.jar is referenced as **provided** dependency in both web projects and as normal dependency in the ejb project so it gets stored in the EAR lib folder. It explicitly should not be an own ejb module.

**The question:** Can I have any Beans e.g. an `@ApplicationScoped` Bean, in the file **specialBeanlib.jar**, so it is accessible from both **mywar1.war** and **mywar2.war** via `@Inject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be fine. During the compile time, since you provide the specialBeanlib.jar as dependency in the Maven, it should appear in the classpath during the compilation of mywar1 and mywar2 modules. During he run-time, since speicalBeanlib.jar is located in the ear\lib folder, which is at the parent classloader of the war classloaders, the bean class should be loaded fine too.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I've created a project from scratch and it works. I'll accept your answer, but some "official" information, e.g. parts of a spec describing this feature, would be useful.